# How to design a horizontal scrolling bar for random selections on Figma?

Tags: user-interface, prototype, user-experience, figma

I am trying to design a cooking app in Figma and one of the screens I wanted to do a surprise me funcion where there are 4 categories (cuisine type, main protein, vegetables, and carbs) and they shuffle through a bunch of options for each and ultiamtely land on one option for each category. (Think of those slot machine games where it spins and slowly, hopefully, lands on the 7) Ideally, users can then shuffle all the options again or shuffle them indiduvally.

[Here is what it looks like in Design mode now on Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVKtd.png)

However, I am running into issues on how to make that happen for a prototype.  Any suggestions are very appreciated and I am also open to a different way of designing that will still allow for random options of those 4 categories.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try the "generate" method. Please see my attached design.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPi1A.png)